# Value in array getting un rounded

Tags: php, variables, rounding

Here is the code within a method of a class:

```
        $this->p($result);//die();
        $this->spreadSheet($result);  //die();
        $this->p($result);die();
```

Result of first print call(this->p)

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [BLOCK_ID] => 537-14547
                    [SawnOn] => Gang saw
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 179.67
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 103.38
                    [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 2413.92
                    [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
                    [SLABCOUNT] => 20
                    [totalSlabVolume] => 117.48
                    [totalSurfaceArea] => 1127.78
                    [totalValue] => 9563.56
                    [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/22/2013
                    [1st Quality] => 100
                    [Second Quality] => 0
                    [Standard Slab] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [BLOCK_ID] => 618-11523
                    [SawnOn] => Gang saw
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 241.46
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 171
                    [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 11858.85
                    [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
                    [SLABCOUNT] => 56
                    [totalSlabVolume] => 143.44
                    [totalSurfaceArea] => 2295.03
                    [totalValue] => 21687.43
                    [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/29/2013
                    [1st Quality] => 91.07
                    [Second Quality] => 7.14
                    [Standard Slab] => 1.79
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [BLOCK_ID] => 237-14593
                    [SawnOn] => Gang saw
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 312.5
                    [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 260.23
                    [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 12061.66
                    [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
                    [SLABCOUNT] => 40
                    [totalSlabVolume] => 160.27
                    [totalSurfaceArea] => 1538.55
                    [totalValue] => 14016.18
                    [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/22/2013
                    [1st Quality] => 0
                    [Second Quality] => 17.5
                    [Standard Slab] => 82.5
                )

        )
```

Result of second print out:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [BLOCK_ID] => 537-14547
        [SawnOn] => Gang saw
        [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 179.67
        [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 103.38
        [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 2413.92
        [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
        [SLABCOUNT] => 20
        [totalSlabVolume] => 117.48
        [totalSurfaceArea] => 1127.78
        [totalValue] => 9563.56
        [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/22/2013
        [1st Quality] => 100
        [Second Quality] => 0
        [Standard Slab] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [BLOCK_ID] => 618-11523
        [SawnOn] => Gang saw
        [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 241.46
        [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 171
        [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 11858.85
        [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
        [SLABCOUNT] => 56
        [totalSlabVolume] => 143.44
        [totalSurfaceArea] => 2295.03
        [totalValue] => 21687.43
        [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/29/2013
        [1st Quality] => 91.06999999999999
        [Second Quality] => 7.14
        [Standard Slab] => 1.79
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [BLOCK_ID] => 237-14593
        [SawnOn] => Gang saw
        [ORIG_VOLUME_BRUT] => 312.5
        [ORIG_VOLUME_NET] => 260.23
        [COUTS_TOTAUX] => 12061.66
        [COUTS_TRANSPORT] => 0
        [SLABCOUNT] => 40
        [totalSlabVolume] => 160.27
        [totalSurfaceArea] => 1538.55
        [totalValue] => 14016.18
        [RECEPTION_DATE] => 03/22/2013
        [1st Quality] => 0
        [Second Quality] => 17.5
        [Standard Slab] => 82.5
    )
```

)

Now see the value for 1st quality in Array[1] of second output. It has changed from 91.07 to  91.0699999999.
What could have possibly caused this?

Here is the code for the 2 methods called in the code above:

```
    function spreadSheet($blocks)
{
    $this->excel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maper")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Maper")
        ->setTitle("Maper")
        ->setSubject("Maper")
        ->setDescription("Maper")
        ->setKeywords("Maper")
        ->setCategory("Maper");
     $i=1;
    $col='A';
    $columns = $this->tableHeadings;
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col++ . $i, $column);
    }


    foreach($blocks as $columns)
    {
        $i++;
        $col = 'A';
        foreach($columns as $column)
        {
            if($col=='A')$sheetName=$column;
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col++ . $i, $column);

        }
       $this->_addSheet($sheetName);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getHyperlink()->setUrl("sheet://'".$sheetName."'!A1");

    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Blocks');
    $this->setStyles();
    //$this->_forceSpreadsheetDownload();
    $this->_saveSpreadsheet();


}
```

the p method:

```
    function p($arr)
{
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo"</pre>";
}
```

Comment: are `p` and `spreadsheet` user defined functions? what do they do?

Comment: It's not a rounding issue. It's a floating point precision limitation. Read the large warning on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: @jbabey p is a method within same class: and merely does this: echo"<pre>";print_r($array);echo"</pre>". The spreadsheet method saves the array to a spreadsheet using phpexcel class. They both are defined with the same class. The containing class extends the phpExcel class.

Comment: why to execute that line again ?

Comment: @Deepanshu I am trying to debug this application. This fetches data from SQL and outputs to html table and gives option to save data as spreadsheet. The html table is giving this one value unrounded. the output in the spreadsheet is fine. but the call to the spreadsheet method is somehow modifying the $result variable (in fact just one value in the array)